# Finding Co-prime numbers without using GCD method

Tags: greatest-common-divisor

Is it possible to know if two given numbers are co-prime or not without using any standard GCD algorithm?I have used Euclidean,Binary GCD & Lehmer's algorithm. If possible suggest a method faster than these.The two numbers can be as large as 10^5 so generating a Faray Sequence will also be of no use.

Comment: How fast does it need to be? Just using a basic GCD implementation of a coprime test in c# only takes an average of around 110 nanoseconds for random ints up to the maximum range of 32 bit ints. In the range you mentioned, the time would be even less.

Comment: I am given an array of numbers,the size of the array can range upto 10^5 & each number in the array can be at max 10^5.that's why I want to avoid the GCD implementation

Comment: My point is that GCD is not that bad performance-wise. Post your fastest code you have so far. It may not be GCD, it may be your implementation. There are ways to improve performance. For example, this initial bit twiddle `(x | y) & 1` can filter out cases where both numbers are even, which should be 25% of the time given random inputs, and takes almost no time at all.

Comment: @hatchet
http://ideone.com/uYCeiN
It has only the gcd code snippet

Answer (score 3):

You may find one of these two simple implementations faster than the function you linked to in your comment. It is c# code, but should be easy to convert to c or java. These are geared for unsigned int, but writing a version for another type should be straightforward.

```
public static uint Gcd(uint value1, uint value2) {
    while (value1 != 0) {
        uint t = value2 % value1;
        value2 = value1;
        value1 = t;
    }
    return value2;
}

public static uint GcdR(uint value1, uint value2) {
    return (value1 == 0) ? value2 : GcdR(value2 % value1, value1);
}
```

In seems like it would be slower because of the modulo operator, but in c# at least, it is more than twice as fast as the function you linked (after converting it to c#). I find the first, non-recursive version slightly faster. You'll have to benchmark to see if either is faster than what you have, for the language you're using. The IsCoprime that uses Gcd looks like this

```
public static bool IsCoprime(this uint value1, uint value2) {
    // 25% of possible pairings are even num to even num so handle them
    // with a bit twiddle that's much faster than GCD function. If they
    // are both even, then they can't be coprime (2 is common divisor).
    return ((((value1 | value2) & 1) != 0)
            && (Gcd(value1, value2) == 1));
}
```